# I cannot increase my disk space using Gparted in Vmware

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, gparted, vmware, resize

I have a Ubuntu OS provided by my teacher that has preinstalled programs in order for us to work from home. The problem is that it almost runs out of storage memory and I would like to expand it.

I have resized  in settings the disk to 20 GB (it was 7GB from the beginning). The problem is that using Gparted I cannot resize since another partition sda2 is in the way.

I do google search a bit and I need to remove it in order for me to be able to resize. The delete button, however, is disabled and I do not know what to do. Also, I do not know what sda2 contains. Is it a good idea to remove it to resize or can it contain like data from the programs my teacher provided in the image?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sda2` contains swap space. When your VM runs out of RAM, it will temporarily move some sections of the RAM to the swap space to make room. You cannot delete/move it, because it is currently in use. You can use the command `swapoff -a` to deactivate it. Then you will be able to move it.

However, you will then be faced with the problem that you cannot resize `sda1` (which is what you actually want to do), because it is in use too.

There are ways to resize a file system while it is in use. However, it is safer (and easier) when a file system is not in use.

The easiest way would be to download an ISO of a Ubuntu live CD and boot the VM from this live CD. The live CD comes with gparted, so you can launch it from within the live CD. The live CD probably makes use of swap, so you need to deactivate it using `swapoff -a`. The file system in `sda1` is not used by the live CD, so you can resize it. Once you are done applying your changes, just shutdown the live CD, remove it from the VM and start your system as usual.